# Given $H$ and $K$ are infinite. Show that $\frac{H-K}{H^2 + K^2}$ is infinitesimal.

Tags: calculus

I'm going through Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach by Keisler. Problem set $1.5$ question $24$. I've tried every rearrangement I can think of but I always end up with an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=\max(H,K)$. Then $|H-K|\lt M$ and $H^2+K^2\gt M^2$. Thus
$$\left|\frac{H-K}{H^2+K^2}\right|\lt \frac{1}{M}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to show: $\displaystyle \lim_{H,K \to \infty} \dfrac{H-K}{H^2+K^2} = 0$.

You have: $\big|\dfrac{H-K}{H^2+K^2}\big| \leq \dfrac{|H|}{H^2+K^2} + \dfrac{|K|}{H^2+K^2} < \dfrac{1}{H} + \dfrac{1}{K}$.

So let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, choose $M > \dfrac{2}{\epsilon}$. Then if $H, K > M$, then:

$\dfrac{1}{H} < \dfrac{1}{M} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$, and also $\dfrac{1}{K} < \dfrac{1}{M} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$.

So: $\big|\dfrac{H-K}{H^2+K^2}\big| < \dfrac{1}{H} + \dfrac{1}{K} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} + \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$, and the conclusion follows.

Comment: Your guess is not quite right. In the book *"Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach"* refer to the *real* infinitesimal, not as a limit.